# I am getting error for my first hibernate program, please help me to resolve the erros

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

**Errors :**

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version). log4j:WARN Please initialize
>   the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
>     at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
>     at org.koushik.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:20)
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database
>   "5432/hibernatedb" does not exist     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:691)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:159)   at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)     at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:283)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
>     ... 5 more

**code**

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 

  <hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/5432/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property> -->

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="org.javabrains.koushik.dto.UserDetails" />
    <!--    <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
package org.javabrains.koushik.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

@Id 
private int userID;
private String userName;

public int getUserID() {
    return userID;
}
public void setUserID(int userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}





}
```

**HibernateTest.java**

```
package org.koushik.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

import org.javabrains.koushik.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserID(1);
        user.setUserName("First user");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j hibernate error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489758/log4j-hibernate-error)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it may be an error in your connection URL. Shouldn't it be

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb`

?

Comment: but dont know how to resolve these errors.. :( please help me out

Comment: Anjali, look at your own code. It has a possible typo in the configuration file.

Comment: hmm ... but i check conf file more than thrice time i am not able to figure out ..

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection URL path it should be like this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
```

If this doesn't work then note that in PostgreSQL's case it's typical to use port 5432 if it is available. If it isn't, most installers will choose the next free port, usually 5433. So you may enter the property like this

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/hibernatedb</property>
```

If you still can't figure out then read this line in your stacktrace you may get the idea what @RemyG is trying to say:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "5432/hibernatedb" does not exist at
```